# Specialize inner class

Tags: c++, templates

Is it possible to specialize a inner class declared within a template class? More or less like the following example (which doesn't work):

```
template<unsigned N>
class Outer {
    struct Inner {
        typedef int Value;
    };
    typedef typename Inner::Value Value;
};

template<>
struct Outer<0>::Inner {
    typedef float Value;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best solution I found is to move `Inner` outside.

```
template<unsigned N>
struct Inner {
    typedef int Value;
};

template<>
struct Inner<0> {
    typedef float Value;
};

template<unsigned N>
class Outer {
    typedef typename Inner<N>::Value Value;
};
```

Comment: To be equivalent, you'll need `friend class Inner<N>;` and `typedef Inner<N> Inner;`

Comment: @Ben Voigt: Due to a defect in the standard, inner classes weren't considered `friend`s of the class that contained it. It's been resolved long ago and several compilers implemented it that way even though it wasn't really valid.

Comment: @K-ballo: C++ doesn't have "inner classes".  This is a nested type, and yes it does have the same access as any other member.  What the standard may have said at some point in the distant past is hardly relevant, because as you say, the defect was resolved long ago.  Also it is a *member*, not a *friend*, which is important because friendship isn't transitive.

Answer (score 3):

It can be done, but not like you try to. You have to specialize the whole outer type:

```
template<>
struct Outer<0>
{
    struct Inner {
        typedef float Value;
    };
    typedef float Value;
};
```

Comment: Thanks, I knew that. I can also move the "Inner" class outside and make it template, then do something like `typedef typename Inner<N>::Value;` with a dependent paramenter on `N` instead.

Comment: @Giovanni Funchal: Then move the `Inner` class outside, what do you possibly gain from it being a nested class?

Comment: Only thing I can think of is being private. Moving it outside makes it a global symbol.

Comment: @Giovani Funchal: Go with standard practice and place your class in a `detail` namespace (or `impl` or `private_`)